# PowerShell unable to find type of exception in try/catch block

Tags: powershell, exception, types, azure-powershell, azure-function-app

I'm running a PowerShell Function App (`~3`) which uses the `Az` PowerShell module to manage a Storage Account. If any of the operations I carry out result in an error, I am unable to check for specific types in a `try`/`catch` block.

**It is important to note that where there is no error, operations using the `Az.Storage` module are successful.**

For example, if I were to try and delete a container that does not exist, the example below results in the following error -

> Unable to find type [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceNotFoundException].

To obtain the type of exception that is returned, I'm using `$_.Exception.GetType().fullname`.

I've also tried to add the namespace to the script that may produce the exceptions.

```
using namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common
```

#### Example

```
Class Storage
{
    [AppSettings]$AppSettings = [AppSettings]::GetInstance()
    [Object]$Context

    Storage()
    {
        $key = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $this.AppSettings.StorageAccountResourceGroup -Name $this.AppSettings.StorageAccountName
        $this.Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $this.AppSettings.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $key[0].Value
    }

    [void] DeleteBlobContainer([String]$name)
    {
        try {
            Remove-AzStorageContainer -Name $name -Context $this.Context -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceNotFoundException] {
            throw [ContainerNotFoundException]::new($name)
        }
        catch {
            throw [DustBinException]::new($_.Exception.Message)
        }
    }
}
```

## Update

When calling an HTTP triggered function, I am able to see that the `Az.Storage` module is installed. This is expected, given operations that require the module are successful -

```
Get-Module -Name Az.Storage -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name, Version, ModuleBase | ConvertTo-Json
[
  {
    "Name": "Az.Storage",
    "Version": {
      "Major": 3,
      "Minor": 0,
      "Build": 0,
      "Revision": -1,
      "MajorRevision": -1,
      "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "ModuleBase": "C:\\Users\\dgard\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctions\\DustBin\\ManagedDependencies\\201202095548376.r\\Az.Storage\\3.0.0"
  }
]
```

However, if copy the module to **.\bin** and include a Module manifest to require **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll**, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837447/powershell-unable-to-find-type-when-using-ps-5-classes), the type is still not found.

```
New-ModuleManifest ./Modules/StorageHelper/StorageHelper.psd1 -RootModule StorageHelper.psm1 -RequiredAssemblies .\bin\Az.Storage\3.0.0\Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.dll
```

To be sure I was adding the correct assembly, I have updated the manifest to include every single assembly in the `Az.Storage` module, but the type is still not found.

Comment: This is `ResourceNotFoundException`. I haven't tried it yet. But I hope you will be able to get it.

Comment: The [exception type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.storage.common.resourcenotfoundexception?view=azurerm-ps) is public, so your symptom is curious. What happens when you execute `[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceNotFoundException]` stand-alone? A - suboptimal - workaround would be to do string comparison on `$_.Exception.GetType().ToString()` in a single, catch-all `catch` block.

Comment: Is this code part of a `class` definition?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, yes it is. I didn't realise that would make a difference - I'll update the example in my question.

Comment: @DavidGard can you try to install the latest stable version of [Az.Storage 3.0.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Storage/3.0.0)? I'm using it and your code can work well.

Comment: @IvanYang - I already have 3.0.0 installed. I'll update my question to make that more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In my question I added an update mentioning that I had tried to add a module manifest requiring all of the `Az.Storage` assemblies; this was not quite correct...

I had copied the list of required assemblies from the module manifest included with the `Az.Storage` module, but this did not include `Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Storage.dll`. Using a module manifest to require this assembly (just this one, no others required) has worked.

```
New-ModuleManifest ./Modules/StorageHelper/StorageHelper.psd1 -RootModule StorageHelper.psm1 -RequiredAssemblies .\bin\Az.Storage\3.0.0\Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Storage.dll
```