# Powershell: Use user32.dll in .psd1 file

Tags: powershell

Environment: Win 10 64 bit, PS version 7.1

I had a module and I decided to move everything into class based. To use the assembly I need to load the .dll etc via the workaround psd1 file.

After look at the thread: [Powershell: Unable to find type when using PS 5 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837447/powershell-unable-to-find-type-when-using-ps-5-classes/42839957#42839957)

**Per comment from @mklement0 the .dll can't be loaded as the same way as the assmebly 'System.Windows.Forms'

**updated per suggestion from @mklement0 but it still didn't work**
This is what it looks like after the update:

```
H:\PowerShell\Modules\TestUtils

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           2/26/2021  6:25 AM           4168 TestUtils.psd1
-a---           2/26/2021  6:22 AM            449 TestUtils.psm1
```

and TestUtils.psd1 was created by command:

> New-ModuleManifest TestUtils.psd1 -RootModule  TestUtils.psm1
> The content in .psm1 is as below:

```
Add-Type -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32 -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int info);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
'@  

Class MyWinUtils
{
    
    Static [Void] ClickLeftMouse([int]$x,[int]$y)
    {
      [Win32.NativeMethods]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0) 
    }
}
```

When I load the module the error popped up:

```
using module TestUtils
InvalidOperation: At TestUtils.psm1:15 char:5
+       [Win32.NativeMethods]::mouse_event(6,0,0,0,0)
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [Win32.NativeMethods].
```

Thanks

Comment: FWIW in PS 5.1 I have psm1 files with classes in them and they are loaded fine when you use `using module` syntax instead of `Import-Module`.

Comment: I always add Win32 types using Add-Type -TypeDefinition <C# code>. I also saw that the C# code is missing the required using statements to use PInvoke (System.Runtime.InteropServices is required for DllImport.)

Comment: @bluuf, _not_ having to add these `using` statements and _not_ having to define an enclosing class explicitly is the convenience that `-MemberDefinition` affords - its primary use is to facilitate exposing P/Invoke-based methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't require `user32.dll` as an *assembly***, because it isn't one: **it is an *unmanaged* DLL, unrelated to .NET**.

Instead:

- Use only `RequiredAssemblies = 'System.Windows.Forms', 'System.Drawing'` to ensure that these *managed* DLLs (assemblies) are loaded.
- Also add a `*.psm1` file to your module directory, using the same name as the module directory as the base name.
- Reference that `*.psm1` file  - by file *name* only - from the module manifest's `RootModule` property.
- Place the [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) `-MemberDefinition` call directly in the top-level scope of the `*.psm1` file.

  - The C# code passed to that call is capable of locating the unmanaged `user32.dll` DLL due its being located in the standard SYSTEM32 directory.

Then, when your module is imported, the `Add-Type -MemberDefinition` command is executed and adds the `[Win32.NativeMethod]` class with its static `mouse_event()` and `ShowWindowAsync()` methods to your session.

---

The update to your question reveals an **additional, *unrelated* problem**:

- You're trying to use the `Add-Type`-added .NET type in the context of a *PowerShell custom class* defined in the same file.
- However, PowerShell parses class definitions at *parse* time rather than at *runtime*, which means that it requires types being referenced in a `class` definition to have been loaded into the session *beforehand*.

**Workaround**:

- Place the `Add-Type -MemberDefinition` call in a *separate* `*.psm1` file inside your module directory, say `helper.psm1`, and reference that file from the `NestedModules` property in the manifest (`NestedModules = @('helper')`).

Nested modules are processed *before* the main (root) module (`RootModule` property), so by the time the `MyWinUtils` class definition is parsed, the `[Win32.NativeMethods]` type has already been loaded.