# How to derive a class from System.Windows.Forms.TabPage in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I wrote a graphical user interface in Powershell, which should display different tabs. From a simplified point of view the program uses two files. The *main.ps1* file uses a System.Windows.Forms.Form object as main windows. This form uses a  System.Windows.Forms.TabControl object for the different tabs. The tabs are then created in the second file (*mytab.psm1*). Therefore, a System.Windows.Forms.TabPage is used. 
I've implemented that in two ways.

- First, I added them as a normal member variable in a class. This approach worked just fine.
- Second, I decided to derive the *MyTab* class from the System.Windows.Forms.TabPage class to make use of the object oriented programming style. But this resulted in the following error:

```
+ class MyTab : System.Windows.Forms.TabPage{    
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.TabPage].
```

---

Here is the simplified code of the *main.ps1* file:

```
Using module .\mytab.psm1

$ApplicationForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$ApplicationForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$ApplicationForm.Text ='My GUI app'

$FormTabControl = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl 
$FormTabControl.Size = "620,380" 
$FormTabControl.Location = "2,2" 
$ApplicationForm.Controls.Add($FormTabControl)

# uncomment this for the first approach -->
# $MyTab = [MyTab]::New([ref]$FormTabControl)
# <-- 

# uncomment this for the second approach -->
# $MyTab = [MyTab]::New()
# $FormTabControl.Controls.Add($MyTab)
# <--

[void] $ApplicationForm.ShowDialog()
```

And here is the simplified code for the *mytab.psm1* file

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Drawing'
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'


# uncomment this for the first approach 
# class MyTab{
#     $TabPage
#     [ref]$TabControl

#     MyTab([ref]$TabControl){
#         $this.TabControl = $TabControl
#         $this.TabPage = New-object System.Windows.Forms.Tabpage
#         $this.TabControl.Value.Controls.Add($this.TabPage)
#     }
# }
# <--


# uncomment this for the second approach
# class MyTab : System.Windows.Forms.TabPage{

# }
# <---
```

In case you need some information on the powershell version, this is the output of $PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

---

Now to the question: 
Why those the script not find *System.Windows.Forms.TabPage* even though it is found in the first approach? 
Am I misinterpreting something? I would accept it, if powershell can not derive from that type. But why isn't it found?

Thanks in advance, 
Mario.

Comment: I may be mistaken on this, but it sounds like you have hit fairly common problem as described by this answer: [PowerShell refuses to run scripts that contains class definitions that reference then-unavailable (not-yet-loaded) types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42839957/4190564)

Comment: In principle, placing `using assembly System.Windows.Forms` at the top of _`main.ps1`_ would solve the problem (it would make the WinForms types available _before_ `mytab.psm1` is parsed). Regrettably, however, in _PowerShell (Core)_ up to at least v7.3.7 (but not in _Windows PowerShell_), `using assembly` statements with well-known assemblies are _broken_  - see [GitHub issue #11856](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11856).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue @Darin posted solved my problem. I had to add a manifest (*.psd1) file to my module like it is described in the post.